# Elm 0.19 Elm.MODULENAME.embed is not a function

Tags: elm

I'm trying to create a simple Elm project that just inserts the "hello world!" string into a div.

Here's my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>ELM Course</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hello-world"></div>

    <script src="hello.js"></script>

    <script>
      const myDiv = document.getElementById("hello-world");
      const app = Elm.Hello.embed(myDiv);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

src/Hello.elm

```
module Hello exposing (..)

import Html exposing (text)


main =
    text "Hello world!"
```

and I compile javascript with the following command:

```
elm make src/Hello.elm --output=hello.js
```

The issue arises when I try to open the index.html with a browser and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Elm.Hello.embed is not a function
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `embed` function has been removed in favor of `init`. Change the javascript on the `const app` line to:

```
const app = Elm.Hello.init({ node: myDiv });
```